# Tableview inside container view overflow issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView embedded inside a container view. When ever I scroll the UITableView inside the container view. The tableview bounces and hides the very bottom cell UITableView. You can't tap on the final cell because it's hidden below the screen. I have tried setting the Bounce Vertically to false-on the table view. But When I do this, the table view stops scrolling at all.

Is there any work around this issue?

Comment: What you need to check first:
1) Constraints
2) Does the height of the container equal to height of the tableView?

Comment: I have a constraint on the container view to match that of the superview. Should I be adding a constant constrain ?

Comment: fixed it - on the container view I unchecked the autoresize subviews.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to check first: constraints; does the height of the container equal to height of the tableView?

ContainerView:

[image]

TableView:

[image]